# Just implemented SSL. My tripadvisor widget is broken/won't show. Anyone know why?

Tags: ssl, widget, tripadvisor

If you can help me make this self-rating widget show up on an SSL site - most appreciated.

```
<div id="TA_cdsratingsonlynarrow580" class="TA_cdsratingsonlynarrow">
  <ul id="dF0s584INkwO" class="TA_links kjnywQtL">
    <li id="wA7uHohwd" class="xMdwzDT2ZgOJ">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.ca/">
        <img src="https://www.tripadvisor.ca/img/cdsi/img2/branding/tripadvisor_logo_transp_340x80-18034-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"/>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=cdsratingsonlynarrow&amp;uniq=580&amp;locationId=1146548&amp;lang=en_CA&amp;border=false&amp;display_version=2">
</script>
```

Comment: Reformat code for readability

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What error are you seeing?

Comment: Have added a comment below @DaveMulligan with screen shots

Answer (score 2):

There is a known issue with Tripadvisor widget where in it tries to load a non SSL url while in a an SSL channel. There is a workaround ; please refer the below link

https://thechamplord.wordpress.com/2015/03/25/how-to-make-tripadvisor-widget-work-on-https/

-The script src in the widget is a jscache URL

```
   https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=cdsratingsonlynarrow&amp;uniq=580&amp;locationId=1146548&amp;lang=en_CA&amp;border=false&amp;display_version=2
```

-When you open it in a browser you get the JavaScript snippet it points to.

```
     document.write(<script src="http://www.tripadvisor.com/WidgetEmbed-   cdsratingsonlynarrow?  amp;locationId=1146548&amp;border=false&amp;uniq=580&amp;lang=en_CA&amp;display_version=2"></script>' )
```

-Note that the script src in the snippet points to an HTTP URL

```
     http://www.tripadvisor.com/WidgetEmbed-cdsratingsonlynarrow?amp;locationId=1146548&amp;border=false&amp;uniq=580&amp;lang=en_CA&amp;display_version=2
```

-Now change the script src in your widget with this new URL but with HTTPS protocol/prefix.

```
     <script src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/WidgetEmbed-cdsratingsonlynarrow?amp;locationId=1146548&amp;border=false&amp;uniq=580&amp;lang=en_CA&amp;display_version=2">
```

Comment: Appreciate the reference, but I did find the champ's advice / code. So I added the "s" - to the code, which tripadvisor is also generating on their site for widgets now too. But my result is a tripadvisor logo, but no self rating... should look like this: http://take.ms/D1MQa but instead looks like this: http://take.ms/RWkoN  The image link also points to the root Tripadvisor site, instead of to the specific property listing...

Comment: The Tripadvisor logo without rating is from the static image URL "https://www.tripadvisor.ca/img/cdsi/img2/branding/tripadvisor_logo_transp_340x80-18034-2.png". You need a dynamic image with rating which should ideally be done by the script you are loading from jscache ie,https://www.jscache.com/wejs?..." This might not working as expected as the jscache URL loads a script which points to another HTTP URL which is a problem. As suggested in the post you might want to try changing your "https://www.jscache.com/we" URL with the one mentioned in the scripts it points to, BUT with HTTPS://"

Comment: You get the below script when "https://www.jscache.com/wejs?...." in your widget is accessed. Note the HTTP:// protocol in the scripts URL, which is a problem                                                                                                --- "document.write('<script src=HTTP://www.tripadvisor.com/WidgetEmbed-cdsratingsonlynarrow?amp;locationId=1146548&amp;border=false&amp;uniq=580&amp;lang=en_CA&amp;display_version=2"></script>' )---

Comment: I see what you mean @Roshith - I don't quite understand where to change:  "want to try changing your "jscache.com/we"; URL with the one mentioned in the scripts it points to" - thanks very much

Comment: I will update the answer as URLs are not clearly displayed in the comments.